# How to access the underlying Fabric code in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a business network with hyperledger composer. I have followed the tutorial on composer web site at [composer playground](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) and have made the tutorial-network as well. Now I am facing one issue. after finishing defining your business network, how is it possible to get the underlying Fabric code that is generated? I can't think of a reason why it should be necessary to have it directly, but lets say if for any reason, like having to give Fabric code to your customer for whom you have developed a poc, you need to have that. Is Fabric code being saved somewhere? I have looked into the business network folder; there are only subfolders for models, test, the business network itself, and after you generate the archive file there is only one file with .bna extension. Nothing related to Fabric there!

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the deployment of your business network, an associated Composer runtime is included that can parse model files, query file and acl files, it is also capable of executing your transaction processor functions. In 0.16.x this was achieved by including a JavaScript VM implementation using Go Chaincode to execute the Composer runtime (written in JavaScript) and the transaction processor functions. In Fabric 1.1, chaincode can be written natively as it now supports Node.js chaincode so with Composer beyond 0.16.x (currently 0.19.x at the time of writing) Composer utilizes this and all Go chaincode it used to contain was removed, along with the Javascript VM. It's the composer runtime that parses the model, query and acl files, and the transaction processor functions run natively inside the node.js fabric chaincode container. Nothing is ever compiled to Go.

Answer (score 2):

The smart contract will be saved in different manner in fabric, as composer is just an abstraction over it. You need to search for the location where the chaincode is present inside the peer. There are some [chaincode related commands](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchaincode.html) which can help you in finding out where the chain code is installed. And to the client you can give the .bna file if you are using composer for the development because I am not sure whether the code will be easily readable at fabric level if you are using composer.

Comment: Hi, so in other words can we say there is currently no lets sat "compiler" which can take the .bna file and generate GO or Java fabric code?

Comment: Yes. Because obviously fabric doesn't understand the composer modelling language so there must be something in between converting that language to go, or java